# Comparing HashMaps for Matches and Mismatches

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, comparison

I have two `HashMaps` that is expected to hold Keys which are **identical**, but expect some differences on their values, and perhaps source/target does not contain the key.

```
   Map<String, Double> source = repository.getSourceData();
   Map<String, Double> target = repository.getTargetData();
```

I'm looking to produce a report with `Matched` data values for the keys, `Mismatched` data values for keys, and finally `Keys exist in only one map`.

Using Java 8's `computeIfPresent()` or `computeIfAbsent()`, how can I achieve this? I need to iterate through `source` map, check if a `key` exists in the `target` map, if exists, inspect values are matching or not. when matched, output result to matched collection. when mismatched, output to mismatched container, and finally output no key exists in target.

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think computeIfPresent or computeIfAbsent are appropriate for this:

```
Map<String, Double> source = repository.getSourceData();
Map<String, Double> target = repository.getTargetData();

Map <String, Double> matched = new HashMap<>();
Map <String, List<Double>> mismatched = new HashMap<>();
Map <String, String> unmatched = new HashMap<>();
for (String keySource : source.keySet()) {
    Double dblSource = source.get(keySource);
    if (target.containsKey(keySource)) { // keys match
        Double dblTarget = target.get(keySource);
        if (dblSource.equals(dblTarget)) { // values match
            matched.put(keySource, dblSource);
        } else { // values don't match
            mismatched.put(keySource, new ArrayList<Double>(Arrays.toList(dblSource, dblTarget)));
        }
    } else { // key not in target
        unmatched.put(keySource, "Source");
    }
}
for (String  keyTarget : target.keySet()) { // we only need to look for unmatched
    Double dblTarget = target.get(keyTarget);
    if (!source.containsKey(keyTarget)) {
        unmatched.put(keyTarget, "Target");
    }
}

// print out matched
System.out.println("Matched");
System.out.println("=======");
System.out.println("Key\tValue");
System.out.println("=======");
for (String key : matched.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key + "\t" + matched.get(key).toString());
}

// print out mismatched
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Mismatched");
System.out.println("=======");
System.out.println("Key\tSource\tTarget");
System.out.println("=======");
for (String key : mismatched.keySet()) {
    List<Double> values = mismatched.get(key);
    System.out.println(key + "\t" + values.get(0) + "\t" + values.get(1));
}

// print out unmatched
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Unmatched");
System.out.println("=======");
System.out.println("Key\tWhich\tValue");
System.out.println("=======");
for (String key : unmatched.keySet()) {
    String which = unmatched.get(key);
    Double value = null;
    if ("Source".equals(which)) {
        value = source.get(key);
    } else {
        value = target.get(key);
    }
    System.out.println(key + "\t" + which + "\t" + value);
}
```